# I am trying to find credit cards using FTK

Tags: grep, computer-forensics

I am doing an assignment where we have to find 5 voyager credit cards using an image file given to us by our professor. The credit cards all start with 8699 and end with 1-5. We are using FTK 1.81.6

```
8699\d{11}[1-5]
```

This is what I came up with to find them but when I search I get no results.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: `grep -oP '\b8699\d{11}[1-5]\b' file`?